# Angular Httpclient service returning data, but printing of the data fails. How to force to await until subscription is finished

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-httpclient

I am buidling a member management application.

I have a component which should print the details of a member.

The component injects 2 services one to retrieve memberdetails, another to retrieve an array of all the country descriptions..

I want to resolve the country based on the countryid stored in the memberdetails.

member-details.component.ts:

```
  memberDetails: Observable<MemberDetailsModel>;
  memberDetailsData: MemberDetailsModel;
  countryList: Country[]  = new Array();
  memberid: number;
  inputsMemberDisabled: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private memberService: MemberService, private globalDataService: GlobalDataService, private router: Router) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputsMemberDisabled = true;
    this.memberid = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    console.log('calling getCountryList: ' + this.countryList);
    this.countryList = this.globalDataService.getCountryList();
    this.getMemberDetails();

  }


  getMemberDetails() {
    this.memberService.getMemberDetails(this.memberid).subscribe(response => {
      this.memberDetails= response;
      this.memberDetailsData = response;
    });
    console.log("getMemberDetails() countrylist: "+ this.countryList)
  }

  mapCountry(id: number): Country {
    console.log('mapCountry: ' + this.countryList);
    for (var i = 0, len = this.countryList.length; i < len; i++) {
      let country = this.countryList.pop();
      if (id === country.id) {
        return country;
      }

    }
    return new Country();
```

So far retrieving the member-details is working fine. But I cannot resolve the country. It says undefined!
[image]

member-details.component.ts (line 21 --)

If I check the output of the global-data service I can see that the Country Objects are being retrieved.
I assume, that the html-component is trying trying to render the country before even the Observable in the global-data service is finished (at least the console logs are giving me empty arrays in the member-details.component.ts)

global-data-service.ts

```
  country: Observable<Country[]>;
  countryList: Country[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getCountryList(): Country[] {
    if (this.countryList.length < 1) {
      console.log("<1");
      this.initializeCountryList().subscribe((res => {
        console.log('countrylist result: ' + res);
        this.countryList = res;
        console.log('countrylist result2: ' + res);
      }));
    }

    return this.countryList
  }

  initializeCountryList(): Observable<Country[]> {
    if (this.countryList.length < 1) {
      //return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/countrylist`).pipe(map(res => res as Country[]
      return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/countrylist`).pipe(map(res => res as Country[]));
}
```

Country.ts:

```
export class Country {
  id: number;
  country: string; //This is the data I want to get
  alpha2Code: string;
  alpha3Code: string;
  numericcode: string;

}
```

I am really frustrated as I have already tried multiple ways over a week now :) but without success.

Thx for suggestions.

**EDIT:**
MemberDetailsModel:

```
import {Memberstate} from "./memberstate";
import {Member} from "./member";
import {Contactinformation} from "./contactinformation";
import {Paymentinformation} from "./paymentinformation";


export class MemberDetailsModel {
  member: Member;
  state: Memberstate;
  contactinformations: Contactinformation[];
  paymentinformation: Paymentinformation;
}
```

Member:

```
import { Membertype} from "../enums/membertype.enum";

export class Member {
  //properties from mm_mem

ber
      id: number;
      memberid: number;
      mainmemberid: number;
      membertype: Membertype;
      firstname: string;
      surname: string;
      birthdate: Date;
      nationality1id: number;
      nationality2id?: number;
      subscriptiondate?: Date;
      recorddate?: Date;
      defaultlanguage:String;
      billcategory: String;
      comment?: String;

    }
```

**EDIT2:**
member-details.component.html:

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar>
      <i class="material-icons md-36">
        face
      </i>
    </div>
    <mat-card-title>Persönliche Daten</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Stammdaten des Mitglieds</mat-card-subtitle>
    <div>
      <i class="material-icons">
        edit
      </i>
      <i class="material-icons">
        save
      </i>
    </div>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Vorname" required [(ngModel)]="memberDetailsData.member.firstname" name="firstname">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Nachname" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.surname}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="true" matInput placeholder="MitgliedsNr." value="{{memberDetailsData.member.memberid}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Mitgliedsart" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.membertype}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Hauptmitglied" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.mainmemberid}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Geburtsdatum" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.birthdate | date}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <!--mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Nationalität 1" value="{{mapCountry(memberDetailsData.member.nationality1id).country}}">
    </mat-form-field-->
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Nationalität 1" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.nationality1id}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Nationalität 2" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.nationality2id}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Anmeldedatum" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.subscriptiondate | date}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Erfassungsdatum" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.recorddate | date}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Bevorzugte Sprache" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.defaultlanguage}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Rechnungskategorie" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.billcategory}}">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <textarea [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" matInput placeholder="Kommentar" value="{{memberDetailsData.member.comment}}"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!inputsMemberDisabled" (click)="toggleDisabledInputs()">Bearbeiten</button>
    <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="warn" [disabled]="inputsMemberDisabled" (click)="updateMemberInformation()">Speichern</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: In the template, try replacing all `memberDetailsData.member` with `memberDetailsData?.member`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `getCountryList()` function of `global-data-service` service, you are returning a plain array of `Country` but it is retrieved internally from an Observable. It would serve you better to return an observable from the service as well. This way, we can be sure `this.countryList` variable in `member-details` component is assigned correct value.

global-data-service.ts

```js
getCountryList(): Observable<Country[]> {
  const result = Subject<Country[]>();

  if (this.countryList.length < 1) {
    this.initializeCountryList().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.countryList = res;
        result.next(res);
      }
    );
  }

  return result.asObservable();
}
```

member-details.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.inputsMemberDisabled = true;
  this.memberid = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  this.globalDataService.getCountryList().subscribe(countries => { this.countryList = countries });
  this.getMemberDetails();
}
```

- In the HTML template, use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to make sure the variable is defined first before accessing it's properties. So replace all instances of `memberDetailsData.member` with `memberDetailsData?.member`. It is equivalent to checking if `memberDetailsData` is defined before accessing it's properties. If you need to check if sub-properties exist you could continue like `memberDetailsData?.member?.firstname`.

Comment: Hey Micheal, thx for your answer it is working. But still I had issues that the countryList was not initialized. So I injected the service into app.component.ts and called init() there. So the list was initialized during access in the member-details.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` directive in the template part, where you are printing your data to check for whether data is set or not. If set it will display the data,else that block wont be rendered in the DOM. Like

```
<div *ngIf = "memberDetailsData">

  <!-- Template part goes here -->

</div>
```

Or you can use ternary operation while accessing the members of the object.

`memberDetailsData?.member` while assigning the values to the input fields.

Hope is solves your problem